# How do I implement the counter from this for cycle to a list by comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, counter

How can i write this code

```
def Serie_a(n):
    Serie_a = []
    m=0
    for i in [1..n]:
        m = m + 1/i
        Serie_a.append(m)
    print Serie_a
```

in the form of a list by comprehension?

Comment: If you just want the last element (which you probably don't but just conjecturing), you can do `result = reduce(lambda x, y: x + 1/float(y), range(1, n+1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you can't write a list comprehension that would be as easy to read as your `for` loop. Instead, use `itertools.accumulate`.

```
>>> list(accumulate(range(1,11), lambda acc, x: acc + 1/x))
[1, 1.5, 1.8333333333333333, 2.083333333333333, 2.283333333333333, 2.4499999999999997, 2.5928571428571425, 2.7178571428571425, 2.8289682539682537, 2.9289682539682538]
```

In Python 3.8, [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) will allow you to write

```
% ./python.exe
Python 3.8.0a2 (tags/v3.8.0a2:23f4589b4b, Mar 18 2019, 15:16:44)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> m = 0
>>> [m := m + 1/x for x in range(1,11)]
[1.0, 1.5, 1.8333333333333333, 2.083333333333333, 2.283333333333333, 2.4499999999999997, 2.5928571428571425, 2.7178571428571425, 2.8289682539682537, 2.9289682539682538]
```

Note that `m` needs to be initialized before it can be used in the list comprehension, though.